# Reading environment variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to achieve something like this.

I am getting a json response after hitting a particular api command (a curl command let's say). I need to convert this result to an html. For this I am thinking of storing the result in an environment variable.
My intentions is to read this variable and so read the json data.

How can I read a environment variable in js?

I am using below program to map the json to html table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
    <style>
        th, td, p, input {
            font:14px Verdana;
        }
        table, th, td 
        {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
    <p id="showData"></p>
</body>

<script>
    function CreateTableFromJSON() {

var myBooks = [
            {
                "Book ID": "1",
                "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                "Category": "Computers",
                "Price": "125.60"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "2",
                "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
                "Category": "Programming",
                "Price": "56.00"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "3",
                "Book Name": "Popular Science",
                "Category": "Science",
                "Price": "210.40"
            }
        ]

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by environment variable ? and what is your issue since your code works and generate the expected table ?

Comment: Yes, But the json in the code is hard coded . This json response would come as a response from an api when executing a binary file.

Comment: and can't you get the result from your api with a simple ajax request ?

Comment: I will look into mentioned options then. I thought if we could read the env variables, I will do this way. Question should not have been downvoted :(

Comment: edit your answer by providing informations about your api and you should get some helps

Answer (score -1):

As Quentin says: you can't, but look into `Local Storage` instead.

Comment: There is no way to use curl to inject data into local storage.

Comment: The OP has already implied that he is able to run JS, so presumably he _does_ have access to local storage etc.

Comment: The data is coming from `curl` which can't be run from client-side JS, so the tool which has access to the data doesn't have access to Local Storage.

Comment: @Quentin The OP _does not_ say that he is using CURL, he uses that as an example of the API that is requesting from. Perhaps the OP would like to clarify, but the tags only mention JS and HTML so you are jumping way too far with your conclusions.

Comment: The question is asking how to get the data from the API into JavaScript. Only JavaScript can put data into local storage, so in order to use local storage for this you need to get the data into JavaScript … at which point the problem is already solved and there is no point in involving local storage.

Comment: That assertion contradicts your first comment. Still no supporting clarification from the OP

Comment: There's no contradiction between my statements (one of which is about what is possible, the other is about what the question is asking).

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript, running client-side in an HTML document, has no access to environment variables at all. So you can't.

Comment: Stop using the curl command line application. Write a program which can make the HTTP request and generate the HTML from the response. Possibly Ajax (but the Same Origin Policy might prevent that). Possibly server-side code (but that might hit the API more frequently that you want). Possible a cronjob that generates a static HTML document. Possibly something else. You've got an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's not possible to tell what the solution to the problem is when you've only described a solution that won't work.